# Динамическое обновление части страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть кнопки, при нажатии которых обновляется динамически часть контента. При нажатии на одну кнопку отображается один контент, при нажатии на другую кнопку другой контент. Что я хочу получить, чтоб один контент всегда был открытым, потом уже когда нажимаешь на другой, другой был открыт (посредством mysql). Не могу осознать как можно из этого слепить то, что хочу.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "page1.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
   $('#btn2').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "page2.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
    $('#btn3').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "page3.html",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#content").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
  });
```

```html
 <form>
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Страница 1"> 
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Страница 2">
        <input id="btn3" type="button" value="Страница 3">
 </form>
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn1').trigger('click');
```

В самый конец. Тем самым вы имитируете `click` по первой кнопке, что приводит в свою очередь к `ajax` запросу.